# Defining an interface property as the evaluated version of a generic conditional type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to define an interface that has a method with a conditional function definition.

I.e.,

```ts
interface Test<T> {
    func: T extends string ? () => string : () => number;
}

class TestClass<T extends string> implements Test<T> {
    func = () => "Cats";
}
```

I get the error:

```
Property 'func' in type 'TestClass<T>' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Test<T>'.
  Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? () => string : () => number'`
```

My intention is that TS should *know* I want `() => string` because `T` is declared as extending string. However, it seems to want me to declare a type that covers both sides of the conditional even though (I think) I've already narrowed it.

Comment: This sort of thing comes up a lot when using conditionals as return types.  You probably have to `as` your way out of it.  `as Test<T>`

Comment: If you really want to narrow it down in your implementation, this is what you want: `class TestClass implements Test<string> `, and now it would work. See this:  https://tsplay.dev/rw274N

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this quite a few times, and it looks like the typescript compiler just doesn't support conditional types very well. There's this issue on the typescript repo: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24929, but it has been closed without a fix.

If you want to keep the `TestClass` generic, there is no way around an any cast: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gDyoHzIDeAUMmcjAK4gIAUAlAFxmrIQAekIAJhsllFABzZAH5+YQSBHMQlALYAjaAG5iAX2LE4igYjDIEAGzgY+6LAGETZ3G04QefAcILB5AByMR5jsOcwcfCJScioaBhDyaOQoCDBKKBBkAHJLOH8U5FNskABPNWjNTSA)

however, if you can specify the type of `TestClass`, then this is solvable:
[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gDyoHzIDeAUMmcjAK4gIAUAlAFxmrIQAekIAJhsllFABzZAH5+YQSBHMQlALYAjaAG5iAX2LEEAGzgY+6LAGE9B5MHkAHHRHkRwhzDgHCCJchWp16RUp-IoCDBKKBBkAHJjODAMCLVPTU0gA)